# C# RSA - Custom Modulus causes Exception

Tags: c#, encryption, rsacryptoserviceprovider

I have this fairly basic code which works as I'd expect, note this is only test code stuffed into one method:

```
public string DoStuff(string input, byte[] customModulus)
{
    var _privateKeyXML = "";
    var _publicKeyXml = "";
    using (var rsaServer = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        //var privateKey = rsaServer.ExportParameters(true);
        //privateKey.Modulus = customModulus;
        //rsaServer.ImportParameters(privateKey);
        _privateKeyXML = rsaServer.ToXmlString(true);
        _publicKeyXml = rsaServer.ToXmlString(false);
    }

    var inputBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    using (var rsaClient = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        rsaClient.FromXmlString(_publicKeyXml);
        encryptedBytes = rsaClient.Encrypt(inputBytes, false);
    }
    using (var rsaClient = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
    {
        rsaClient.FromXmlString(_privateKeyXML);
        inputBytes = rsaClient.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false);
    }
    input = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inputBytes);
    return input;
}
```

But if I un-comment the lines which set my customModulus, the `rsaClient.Decrypt` method throws an exception: `System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: 'A device attached to the system is not functioning.'`

My customModulus is a `byte[256]`

Comment: You can't just replace the modulus alone in the parameters, the remaining fields will be inconsistent.

Comment: Good information, and probably the answer sans some unknown unknowns.  I believe somewhere else in the system, that customModulus parameter is possibly the certificate bytes which can be calculated to pull out the other parts of the key parameters, and that I was just under the impression it was only the modulus.  So the correct way to do this, if you want a similar path, is to pull out particular bytes of the `byte[]` into all of the parameters of the key, as you said.